# Is it possible to "zoom" the text in a WPF RichTextBox?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, richtextbox, zooming

I noticed the WinForms RichTextBox has a `ZoomFactor` property that I assume is exactly what I want--unfortunately this seems to be entirely missing on the WPF variant.

Is there any way I can achieve the same functionality (increasing/decreasing the visible text size of the whole document without actually changing the underlying RTF)?

**Update:** While setting a LayoutTransform on the RichTextBox does seem to work under very simple settings, it's not exactly the same as setting ZoomFactor because of a couple things:

- First, the scroll bar is zoomed also. This just looks silly.
- Second, in my app (for some reason, but not in Kaxaml--I'll explore this to figure out why), the text is *bitmap zoomed* so that it just enlarges the rendered text as opposed to vector-zooming it so it's smooth. Here's an example of what I'm talking about (note the way-big custom scroll bar):

[image]

**Update 2:** Okay I discovered that the bitmap zooming was being caused by setting TextOptions.TextFormattingMode to `Display` instead of `Ideal`. Setting it to ideal reintroduces vector zooming.

However there is still that pesky scroll bar! I mean one option is to disable scrolling on the RichTextBox and wrap it in a ScrollViewer, but I wonder if that would deteriorate performance. I also wonder if text wrapping would still work if I did that.

Comment: Text wrapping works just fine.  (The harder problem is if you want to turn off text wrapping and use horizontal scrolling.)  And performance doesn't seem any different, nor can I think of a reason it should be.  One thing you'll probably want to do is edit the control template for the `RichTextBox` so that it doesn't have any kind of border chrome, since that gets scaled too, which is dorky looking at 30x magnification.

Comment: My concern about performance is that perhaps the RichTextBox performs some kind of internal virtualization for large documents that wouldn't take place if I wrapped it in a ScrollViewer manually.

Comment: Everything seems to be working fine now, except for the annoying fact that I can't use Display mode for the RichTextBox (I can't even set it to Display mode when zoom factor is 1.0, due to a bug/limitation of the RichTextBox and TextOptions), however this is relatively minor. So far there's no obvious decrease in performance for large RTF files, but then the RichTextBox has always been kinda slow with large RTF documents.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should get you started:

```
<Page
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
  <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">  
     <Slider x:Name="Scale" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Minimum="1" Maximum="20"/>
     <RichTextBox>
      <RichTextBox.LayoutTransform>
        <ScaleTransform ScaleX="{Binding ElementName=Scale, Path=Value}" ScaleY="{Binding ElementName=Scale, Path=Value}"/>
      </RichTextBox.LayoutTransform>
     </RichTextBox>
  </DockPanel>
</P
```

Comment: Hey it works! I'm actually surprised because I can't understand the underlying logic of how adding a transform affects *wrapping* of the text.

Comment: @devios1 have you figure it out the scrollbar zoom issue?

Answer (score 4):

> I noticed the WinForms RichTextBox has
>   a ZoomFactor property that I assume is
>   exactly what I want--unfortunately
>   this seems to be entirely missing on
>   the WPF variant.

You need to get back and read the basics of WPF. Item by Item. Stop at TRANSFORMS. The reason that a ZoomFactor is missing in the TextBox is that EVERY WPF CONTROL can be TRANSFORMED (zoom, 3d transforms) and ANIMATED by generic standard measures - so a special approach is simply unneeded.

Comment: I thought of this, but wouldn't zooming the textbox by a transform simply make the whole thing uniformly bigger? I want the text to still wrap properly, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [FlowDocumentReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.flowdocumentreader.aspx) as I think that has what you are looking for.