# WPF- Richtextbox fontsize zoom factor?

Tags: c#, wpf, fonts, richtextbox

I found that richtextbox in wpf  dosen't have zoomfactor property which gets or sets the current zoom level of the RichTextBox. I wonder if there are any other way to achieve the same function in wpf. Here is the reference site https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.zoomfactor(v=vs.110).aspx

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Joe's answer solves my problem,and I also find another way to achieve the function [another answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3430629/is-it-possible-to-zoom-the-text-in-a-wpf-richtextbox)

Comment: That's a better way of doing it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add zoom functionality by wrapping the rich text box in a ViewBox and setting the width similar to [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38128147/need-to-be-able-to-change-font-size-across-an-entire-application-for-accesibilit/38128890#38128890).

```
<Viewbox>
    <RichTextBox Width="{Binding Width}" Height="{Binding Height}"/>
</ViewBox>
```

With the width and height:

```
private int BaseWidth = 1150;
private int BaseHeight = 750;

public int Width
{
    get
    {
        return (int)(BaseWidth * appSettings.Zoom);
    }
}

public int Height
{
    get
    {
        return (int)(BaseHeight * appSettings.Zoom);
    }
}
```

You will get behavior like this:

[image]

It might need some tweaking, perhaps using the ViewBox width and height and setting the rich text to a multiple of that so it scales with the UX nicely.

**Edit** You can get "2x normal size" scaling, keeping the layout aspect ratio etc using a multibinding like this:

```
<Grid x:Name="MainViewBoxContainer">
    <Viewbox>
        <RichTextBox>
            <RichTextBox.Width>
                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MultiBindingMultiplier}">
                    <Binding Path="ActualWidth" ElementName="MainViewBoxContainer"/>
                    <Binding Path="Zoom"/>
                </MultiBinding>
            </RichTextBox.Width>
            <RichTextBox.Height>
                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MultiBindingMultiplier}">
                    <Binding Path="ActualHeight" ElementName="MainViewBoxContainer"/>
                    <Binding Path="Zoom"/>
                </MultiBinding>
            </RichTextBox.Height>
        </RichTextBox>
    </Viewbox>
```

Where the multi-binding converter:

```
public class MultiBindingMultiplier : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (values.Length > 1)
        {
            try
            {
                double value = (double)values[0];
                for (int i = 1; i < values.Length; i++)
                {
                    value *= (double)values[i];
                }
                return value;
            }
            catch
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```